# Error CS1520. No puedo retornar unos valores

Tags: c#, dotnetcore

Estoy aprendiendo C# y me tope con este error cuando estaba haciendo unas clases, no puedo retornar los valores que necesito para que la función haga su trabajo

Estoy usando Dotnet 6.0.202. Quiero que a se iguale a i, que es igual a 10, y que luego se sume en testClass. Según el depurador, el problema está en:

```
public MyfirstClass(int i){
    a = i;
}
```

Aqui esta el codigo completo

```
MyFirstClass testClass = new MyFirstClass(10);
Console.WriteLine(testClass.GetNumber());
class MyFirstClass{

    int a; //Elemento que no sale de la clase

    public MyfirstClass(int i){
        a = i;
    }

    public int GetNumber(){
        int result = a + 1;
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿`return result.ToString();`? ¿Cómo vas a retornar un `string` si declaras en la firma del método que vas a retornar un `int`? Por otro lado, por favor, explica mejor tu problema, no queda claro. Puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces necesites presionando editar.

Comment: La función GetNumber debe retornar un entero y lo que tu devuelves es un string

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no aporta nada a la comunidad

Comment: Ya lo corregí, pero sigue el problema en el public class. Ahí ocurre el Error CS1520

Comment: El constructor debe llamarse igual que la clase, tienes una f minúscula en lugar de una F mayúscula en `MyfirstClass`. Por otro lado, imprime 11 ¿Qué esperas que imprima?

Comment: Ya funciona, gracias